# Copy constructor not called from function return

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I would expect the following code to print `copy called` twice. Once for the creation of `f2` and once for the creation of `f3`. But for some reason, it is only printed once. Why is this? Is there some type of optimization going on? If so, is there a way to disable it without compiler flags?

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo const&) { std::cout << "copy called" << std::endl; }
};

Foo test()
{
    Foo f1;
    Foo f2(f1);

    return f2;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f3(test());
}
```

Comment: *If so, is there a way to disable it without compiler flags?* -- Why would you want to disable it?  If it's because your real code has side-effects that are undesirable because of the optimization, then your code is flawed.

Comment: No, it is because I want to be able to implement reference counting.

Comment: How is the optimization stopping reference counting from working correctly?  It shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: Because in a more complex piece of code it was (or I thought it was) causing the number of destructions to be different than the number of constructions and that was causing it to destroy the pointer before it should have.

Comment: Well, you just confirmed my original point.  Your code was flawed.  How does `std::shared_ptr` accomplish this?  That is also reference counted.  Bottom line is that you should never write code assuming a copy would be done, and base a set of business logic on that assumption.  The compiler is free to optimize copies away.

Comment: [From the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).  The first sentence sums it all up about side-effects.

Comment: I would like to qoute the notes section of the cppreference link mentioned by @PaulMcKenzie, ```Copy elision is the only allowed form of optimization (until C++14)one of the two allowed forms of optimization, alongside allocation elision and extension, (since C++14) that can change the observable side-effects. Because some compilers do not perform copy elision in every situation where it is allowed (e.g., in debug mode), programs that rely on the side-effects of copy/move constructors and destructors are not portable.```